# c++ Попарное зацикливание в векторе

Tags: c++

Если у меня есть вектор и я хочу проверить все элементы попарно (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4) и **(4, 0)**

```
int main(){
  vector<int> = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  //...
}
```

Какие есть способы зациклить последовательность?
Мне на ум приходят два:

### Сделать дополнительный if внутри,

```
int main(){
  vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
    if(i != vec.size() - 1){
      foo(vec[i], vec[i+1]);
    } else {
      foo(vec[i], vec[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

но это увеличивает время выполнения из-за лишней проверки на каждой итерации.

### или сделать отдельно дополнительную проверку последнего и первого

```
int main(){
  vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i){
    foo(vec[i], vec[i+1]);
  }
  foo(vec[vec.size() - 1], vec[0]);
}
```

Но это решение мне не нравится из-за того, что последняя строка иногда забывается и выглядит оно не особо элегантно.

### Как бы вы посоветовали решить этот вопрос?

Comment: `foo(vec[i], vec[(i+1)%vec.size()]);`

Comment: @Danis, это быстрее чем с `if`'ом?

Comment: @wololo не знаю

Answer (score 2):

Если порядок пар не важен, то есть такой вариант. Выглядит довольно быстрым из-за простого тела цикла:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror pairs.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int prev = vec.back();
    for (int v : vec) {
        foo(prev, v);
        prev = v;
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror pairs.cpp && ./a.out 
> 4 0
> 0 1
> 1 2
> 2 3
> 3 4
> ```

Comment: Весьма хитроумно. Но `Выглядит довольно быстрым` — это всё вилами по воде писано. Тут нужны тесты. Я бы не удивился, если бы в варианте с `if` компилятор сам бы вынес `if` за пределы цикла.

Comment: Моя задача была предоставить оптимизатору возможность работать. В случае с `if` оптимизатор уберет `if` только если убедится что размер вектора не меняется в цикле. Пока мы в рамках примера это возможно, но если вектор приходит снаружи и тело функции `foo` неизвестно компилятору, то всё замедлится. В моём коде гарантия неизменности длины вектора предоставлена, хотя и неявно.

Comment: Кроме того я написал "выглядит" именно потому что не делал тестов.